# To Automatically Add Relative Url to .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

How to make **Angular-Cli** (Angular-4) automatically append URL's to **Style's** or **Script's** when adding external libraries from **npm install --save** into **.angular-cli.json**?

So far, We need to manually traverse into the **node_modules** folder and look for the address of the file and use the same in the **.angular-cli.json**.

Is there any work around ?

Thank You

Regards

Shohil Sethia

Comment: You can't. Not all libraries are the same, therefore the import isn't the same.

Answer (score 1):

use the --base-href https:// to build the project.
like ng build -prod --base-ref http://

Also consider using @angular/cli@1.4.4 or latest if latest is working.

Comment: A code example would be better @fox-jazz,
Please provide one.